# How I should get mean and standard deviation depens on "Day" and "Category" columns without filtering manually in the R code

Tags: r

I am getting Mean and standard deviation while filtering the below-mentioned columns in the R console, but how I should get the mean and SD without filtering the columns "Day" and "Category" without filtering it manually in the code and the result should print in the same CSV itself.

code should automatically create the depends on the column filter like below and print the results in the same CSV:

```
mean_Day1_Category_a, SD_Day1_Category_a,
mean_Day4_Category_b, SD_Day4_Category_b, etc...
```

**data**

```
Sex F_category        Value Day category
M   Food              25.6  1   a
M   Water             22    2   a
M   Food              22    11  a
M   Food             24.3   4   b
M   Food              24    5   b
F   Water            2.03   10  b
```

**code**

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(doBy)
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/food.csv")
print(data)

data_male<- data %>% 
  filter(sex == "M")%>%
  filter(Day == 1)%>%
  filter(F_Category =="FC")%>%
  filter(Category =="a")

data_male

sd(data_male$value)
mean(data_male$value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group the data by day and category instead of filtering.

```
data_male %>% group_by(Day, Category) %>% summarise(avg_val = mean(Value), std_val = std(Value))
```

Comment: I want Mean and SD based on filtering the values by "Day" column, since it has 4000 records, how should get the results without manually filtering "Day" column. also how to create columns mentioned above without manually hard coded in the code